# How to convert docx to pdf file in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, docx, syncfusion

I'm trying to convert a docx file that I made with the docx_template library: ^0.3.3 to PDF, I've tried using libraries to do it. Whit SyncFusion i have this:

```
//Get external storage directory
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    //Get directory path
    String path = directory.path;

    final of = File('$path/Engranes Rectos Sistema Ingles.docx');
    if (d != null) await of.writeAsBytes(d);

    Directory directory2 = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory());
    String path2 = directory2.path;

    final PdfDocument document = PdfDocument(
        inputBytes: File('$path/Engranes Rectos Sistema Ingles.docx')
            .readAsBytesSync());

    //Save the document.
    File file = File('$path/Engranes Rectos Sistema Ingles.pdf');
    await file.writeAsBytes(await document.save(), flush: true);
    //Dispose the document.
    document.dispose();
    OpenFile.open('$path/Engranes Rectos Sistema Ingles.pdf');
```

Comment: And what is your question ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this package or any package that supports input as bytes

https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdf

You can convert the doc to bytes and generate pdf like the following

```
//Load the existing docx document.
final PdfDocument document =
    PdfDocument(inputBytes: File('input.docx').readAsBytesSync());


//Save the document.
File('yourFileName.pdf').writeAsBytes(await document.save());
//Dispose the document.
document.dispose();
```

Comment: this solution doesn't work