# Convert Word Document to PDF in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, docx, doc

Is there a way to convert docx files to pdf in flutter? Or i have to use api.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73001898/7814781) but I'm getting `Not in inclusive range 2048..13473653: 1024`